# SharePoint.com site differences?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, site-collection, site

I just started a sharepoint.com account and am trying to understand the difference between some of the features it has.

I'm coming from SharePoint 2013 currently.  When I log into sharepoint.com, it takes me to the `domain.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/sharepoint.aspx` URL which gives me an option "Create site" from which I can create a team site or a communication site.

I created a team site, but it doesn't show up on this home page unless I add it as a favorite. The site created looks to have an address of `domain.sharepoint.com/sites/Garden` and has the newer layout. However, if I go to `domain.sharepoint.com/SitePages/Home.aspx`, it looks to be a completely different site collection with more of a 2013 layout and does not show the Garden site as a subsite.

I think I'm missing something. Was hoping someone could throw me a bone so I can put the pieces together.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`/sharepoint.aspx` is the SharePoint tile landing page in the App Launcher menu. The site you created is a unique Site Collection residing under the `/sites/` Managed Path, not a subsite of the root Site Collection at `domain.sharepoint.com`.